# How to find the smallest difference between two columns in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database which contains data for recording games between people. I wanted to have a query that would return the game which was closest between two players, ie, the smallest difference between the two scores recorded, regardless of who won. I have started with something like this as a query, but I can't quite get what I want.

```
SELECT recorder_score, opponent_score 
from games 
where recorder_id = $recorder_id 
order by (recorder_score - opponent_score) 
limit 1
```

The above obviously would only return the closest game that the person submitting the game has won, but as I mentioned, I want the closest game regardless of who wins. What will be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Is the recorder always the winner?  What is the id of the opponent?  Please provide your table schema, sample data and expected results.

Comment: The recorder is not always the winner. The opponent ID is not recorded, as opponents may be people who have not registered within the site. The only way of identifying the opponent is an entered name which may vary.  The only relevant columns for this query are what I mentioned: recorder_id, recorder_score, opponent_score. Other columns include game_date, game_id and opponent_name though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ABS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) in `Order by` to get the closest game between two players

```
SELECT recorder_score, opponent_score 
from games 
where recorder_id = $recorder_id 
order by ABS(recorder_score - opponent_score) 
limit 1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I completely forgot about using ABS, thanks for the quick response!